# printf changes for iteration over array

Tags: arrays, bash, printf, snmp

I am playing with a simple bash script to pull some interface info from network equipment using SNMP.

I store a list of IPs in an array and iterate over it to fetch and print data for each device.

The first iteration for *ip1* looks all good, for *ip2+* the output is messed up with a line break as shown below:

```
Interface information for SomeHostname on IP 10.10.10.10
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________                                                                                  
| Interface            | IP-Address/Prefix    | Status       | Interface type       | Last changed              |
| ____________________ | ____________________ | ____________ | ____________________ | __________________________|
| Gi0/0/1.100          | 1.2.3.4/24           | up(1)        | l2vlan(135)          | 157 d 16 h 28 m and 42 s  |
| Gi0/0/1.101          | 2.3.4.5/24           | up(1)        | l2vlan(135)          | 157 d 16 h 28 m and 42 s  |
| Gi0/0/1.102          | 3.4.5.6/24           | up(1)        | l2vlan(135)          | 143 d 7 h 39 m and 15 s   |
etc.

Interface information for SomeHostname on IP 10.10.10.11
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________                                                                                  
| Interface            | IP-Address/Prefix    | Status       | Interface type       | Last changed              |
| ____________________ | ____________________ | ____________ | ____________________ | __________________________|
| Gi0/0/1.100          | 4.5.6.7/24           | up(1)        | l2vlan(135)          | 746                       |
| d                    | 17                   | h            | 3                    | m                         |
| and                  | 26                   | s            |                      |                           |
etc.
```

The code printing this looks something like this:

```
for ip in "${ips[@]}"
do

printf "\nInterface information for $hostname on IP $ip\n"
printf "%-20s %-20s %-12s %-20s %-25s \n" " _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________"
printf "| %-20s | %-20s | %-12s | %-20s | %-25s |\n" "Interface" "IP-Address/Prefix" "Status" "Interface type" "Last changed"
printf "| %-20s | %-20s | %-12s | %-20s | %-25s|\n" "____________________" "____________________" "____________" "____________________" "__________________________"
                              
for ((i=0; i<${#ipAdEntAddr[@]}; i++)); do                              
    if_lastChange[$i]=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c $snmp_community $cpe 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9.${ipAdEntIfIndex[$i]} | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1)
    uptime=$(snmpget -v 2c -c $snmp_community $cpe 1.3.6.1.6.3.10.2.1.3.0 |  sed -e 's/SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineTime.0 = INTEGER: //g' | awk -F" " '{print $1}')
    iflastChange[$i]=$(echo $((${if_lastChange[$i]}/100)))
    ifc1[$c]=$(echo $((($uptime-${iflastChange[$i]}))))
    ifc2[$c]=$(displaytime $ifc1)

    printf "| %-20s | %-20s | %-12s | %-20s | %-25s |\n" ${ifDescr[$i]} ${ipAdEntAddr[$i]}"/"${ipAdEntNetMask[$i]} ${ifOpStatus[$i]} ${ifType[$i]} ${ifc2[$c]}
done
printf "%-20s %-20s %-12s %-20s %-25s \n" " _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________"
done
```

Can somebody point me to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to quote all the variables: `printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %-12s | %-20s | %-25s |\n' "${ifDescr[$i]}" "${ipAdEntAddr[$i]}/${ipAdEntNetMask[$i]}" "${ifOpStatus[$i]}" "${ifType[$i]}" "${ifc2[$c]}"`

Comment: That feeling when you've missed something really obvious ;) Thanks dan!

Comment: `printf` behaves the same inside a loop as it does outside.  The most likely explanation, then, is that the data you are offering to it are not what you intended.  That might be related to your egregious under-quoting, but it looks like most of the data being printed were actually read in some part of the script that you omitted.  Run your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), fix the issues it reports, and if that doesn't resolve the problem then present a [mre].

Comment: to troubleshoot the content of the arrays consider running `typeset -p <array_name>`; this will display the contents (index/value pairs) of the array; do the arrays contain what you're expecting?

Comment: To add to the above, any problem that is trivially reproducible, you can quickly add enough debug statements to determine the unexpected condition. The ineresting problems are the ones that take days, if not weeks to reproduce...